# Formatting a Powershell string containing hashtable values

Tags: powershell, format, hashtable

The answer to this is likely to be trivial, but I have spent half an hour and still can't work it out.

Assume I have a the following hashtable:

```
$hash = @{face='Off';}
```

What I have tried to do, is output the value of "face" along side some other string elements.

This works:

```
Write-Host Face $hash['face']
=> Face Off
```

However, this doesn't:

```
Write-Host Face/$hash['face']
=> Face/System.Collections.Hashtable[face]
```

Somehow the lack of a space has affected the operator precedence - it is now evaluating $hash as a string, the concatenating [face] afterwards.

Trying to solve this precedence problem, I tried:

```
Write-Host Face/($hash['face'])
=> Face/ Off
```

I now have an extra space I don't want.
This works, but I don't want the extra line just to reassign:

```
$hashvalue = $hash['face']
write-host Face/$hashvalue
=> Face/Off
```

Any idea how to get this working as a one-liner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, use a subexpression:

```
Write-Host Face/$($hash['face'])
```

Generally, I'd just use a string, if I need precise control over whitespace with Write-Host:

```
Write-Host "Face/$($hash['face'])"
```

Yes, in this case you need a subexpression again, but more because you simply can't include an expression like `$foo['bar']` in a string otherwise ;-)

By the way, `$hash.face` works just as well with much less visual clutter.

Comment: The subexpression was the key here (enclosing in $()). I was aware vaguely of their role, but had missed the applicability here.

Comment: Unaccepted to give others a chance to answer. Was a bit quick off the blocks

Answer (score 3):

In such cases, and more so if there are more variables involved, I prefer using the string formatting. While in this case you can live with the `$(..)`, be aware that string formatting will remove lot of doubt, cruft and improves readability:

```
write-host ("Face/{0}" -f $hash['face'])
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the -f option. I'd never used that, and I can definitely see how it would make more complex scenarios much more manageable

Comment: llevera, it's an operator, not an option.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using sub expressions as Joey showed you can:

Use string formatting:

```
Write-Host ('Face/{0}' -f $hash.face)
```

This will stick the value of face key in the place of {0}

Use string concatenation:

```
Write-Host ('Face/' + $hash.face)
```

Both of those require an expression to be evaluated which outputs a string which is used as `Write-Host`'s `Object` parameter.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that for the Write-Host ('Face/' + $hash.face) example, the brackets are important. Without them, the + gets treated as a string literal. Powershell string formatting takes a little getting used to!

Comment: @llevera Yea the parens tell PowerShell to execute the string concatenation first. The output is a System.String object which is used as the `Write-Host -Object` parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to insert your slash with the -Separator option of Write-Host:

```
$hash = @{Face="off"}
Write-Host ("Face",$hash.Face) -Separator '/'
```